# Using static_cast in character array to use string functions

Tags: c++, string, casting

I want to use `static_cast` to use string functions like `erase()` and `find()` in a character array, say `char str[50]`. For instance, please consider following segment:

```
char str[]="abcdefghi";
char val[]="bc";
static_cast<string>(str).erase(static_cast<string>(str).find(val[0]),1);
```

Please tell me if it is correct and if it is, then str is not retaining the value it should have, i.e. `"acdefghi"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please tell me if it is correct

It won't work.

`static_cast<string>(str)` will create a temporary `std::string` from `str`, its content is copied from `str`. Any modification on it has nothing to do with the original variable `str`.

You could do this on `std::string`, and convert it back to `const char*` when necessary.

```
string new_str(str);                    // construct std::string
new_str.erase(new_str.find(val[0]), )); // modification on it
cout << new_str.c_str() << endl;        // convert back to `const char*`
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add closing parenthesis after find. It was supposed to be find(val[0]). Now erase() should remove words till length 1 i.e. a single character. Right?  If I do->       char s[]=static_cast<string>(str).erase(static_cast<string>(str).find(val[0]),1); in anoter char array, will it work?

Comment: @KomalJoshi Yes, `find(val[0])` will do what you want. What do you mean ` char s[]=static_cast<string>(str).erase(static_cast<string>(str).‌​find(val[0]),1);`? You can't do that, `std::string` can't be converted to `char[]` directly.

Comment: @songuanyao Thank you so much.I wanted to retain the value I received, but have understood your point. static_cast<string>(str).erase(static_cast<string>(str).‌​‌​find(val[0]),1) won't give me desired result as the cast value in erase(static_cast<string>(str).‌​‌​find(val[0]) will not be retained, as you already explained about temporary string that will be created for cast. So, even if I perform any operation here, it will be temporary and will not persist, hence it won't give me desired result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access char* (raw c string) like an stl container this is **std::experimental::string_view** was invented for. But it will give an access only to read/iterate/find like operations, not modifying. There is also a sad moment - it is delayed for C++17 standard (anyway GCC-6.x already has it). See for **boost::utility::string_view** also. If you want to have modify access for char* I would recommend you using your own wrapper over string with length check, etc.

Here is an example I am talking about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/string_view>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;


typedef experimental::string_view string_view;

class RawStringWrapper : public string_view
{
    char * sstr;
    size_t len;

public:
    RawStringWrapper(char * str, size_t sz)
        : std::experimental::string_view(str, sz),
          sstr(str),
          len(sz){}

    bool erase(const string &s){
        auto pos = find(s);
        if (std::string::npos != pos){
            sstr[pos] = 0;
            strcat(sstr, sstr + pos + s.size());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // ...other modifying functions you need
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char rawString[] = "abcdefgh";
    RawStringWrapper str(rawString, sizeof(rawString));
    str.erase("cde");
    cout << rawString << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will be using it. This was something new for me.